# Как победить несогласованность по доступности типов

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Что делать если класс является `public`, но переданный в него параметр должен быть `internal`?

Простой воспроизводимый пример:

```
public abstract class TypeData
{
    // абстрактный класс
}

public class TypeData<T> : TypeData
{
    // реализация класса
}
```

Далее определим внутренний тип:

```
internal delegate void SomeDelegate(int a, string b);
```

После этого попробуем использовать его в публичном классе:

```
public class TypeDataDelegateContain : TypeData<SomeDelegate>
{
    // реализация дополнительного функционала класса
}
```

Что получаем из этого, так ничего хорошего кроме как ошибку компиляции:

> Несогласованность по доступности: доступность базового класса
>   "TypeData" ниже доступности класса
>   "TypeDataDelegateContain"

Можно ли этого избежать, не раскрывая внутренний делегат?

Comment: Вам вообще такой `internal delegate void SomeDelegate(int a, string b);` делегат не нужен, т.к. уже есть готовый к использованию `Action<int, string>`.

Comment: @Bulson: Не пройдет, делегаты делают вызовы неуправляемого кода, и стоят с пометкой `unsafe` а так же частично работает с указателями, ну еще помимо этого стоит согласование о вызовах.

Comment: @LLENN в вашем случае невозможно, тк вы его ещё и в качестве генерика для открытого класса используете. А в чем смысл такого сокрытия?

Comment: Никак. Зачем свой делегат? Как уже написали в комментариях есть Action.

Comment: @LLENN  хотя можно попробовать что-то в духе TypeDataDelegateContain<T> : TypeData<T> where T: SomeDelegate... Не уверен... Но мало ли

Comment: Ну... , доводы автора про unsafe и всякие там атрибуты вполне, по моему, оправданы. Их к action не прикрутить

Comment: Нельзя конечно, и это логично. Откуда клиент возьмёт экземпляр `SomeDelegate`? Решение есть – вместо делегата заведите абстрактный класс с методом и используйте его уже в качестве дженерик-параметра, ну и потом уже сделайте internal-наследника это класса.